# How to create a file in the directory where the .py script is ran?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a file in the folder I running my .py script. This is the code I am using. The problem is that the open function requires / for directories. new_file_path uses \ instead. This is causing the open function to fail. How do I fix this?

```
import os

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
new_file_path = str(os.path.join(dir_path, 'mynewfile.txt'))
open(new_file_path, "x")
```

Comment: no need to use `str()` function on the result from `os.path.join()`. And post full traceback you get. There is no problem with using forward slash in path

Comment: There's no need for all that... The default will be the current working dir so a simple `open('mynewfile.txt', 'w')` will do the job...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried simply

```
import os

dir_path = os.getcwd()
open(dir_path +'mynewfile.txt', "x")
```

Edit: Sorry for the last message, it saved incomplete

Comment: sorry, that was a sending problem. Please try again with the current code

Comment: First, you need `dir_path + os.path.sep + 'mynewfile1.txt'` or this `open` can't even succeed. Second, by default if you do not specify a directory, the system will attempt to open the file in the current working directory by default (that is the *definition* of the current working directory), so that makes using `os.getcwd()` totally unnecessary. How can *this* be the accepted answer?

Comment: Hello brother. os.getcwd() returns a string containing the current path where the python script was called. using a simple string concatenation, he was able to sucessfully use the function open.(the current path plus the filename). Cheers!

Comment: Then he would have to have been in the root directory `/`. In any other directory, such as `/home/Roni`, `getcwd()` would just return `/home/Roni` without a trailing path separator and your code would not work in the general case (as would blindly adding a path separator would not work if you are in the root directory). That is why you would want to use `os.path.join`, which will work for both cases. So my comment was based on your answer as *a general solution." My other point is that calling `getcwd()` is altogether unnecessary. Just `open('mynewfile.txt', 'x')`..

Comment: That is, *if* you want to open in the current working directory, which can be but not necessarily the same as the directory that holds the script file. And it's not 100% clear from the OP's question (at least not to me), which one he really wants because his attempt is using `__file__`, which is where the file lives, but he likes your getcwd(), which is the current working directory, and again, **they may not always  be the same**.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, as @buran commented, there is no need to use `str`, the following suffices:

```
new_file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, 'mynewfile.txt')
```

There is a distinction between where the script exists, given by `__file__`, and the current working directory (usually the place from which the script was invoked), given by `os.getcwd()`. It is not entirely clear from the question wording which one was intended, although they are often the same. But not in the following case:

```
C:\Booboo>python3 test\my_script.py
```

But they are in the following case:

```
C:\Booboo>python3 my_script.py
```

But if you are trying to open a file in the current working directory, why should you even be bothering with making a call to `os.getcwd()`? Opening a file without specifying any directory should by definition place the file in the current working directory:

```
import os

with open('mynewfile.txt', "x") as f:
    # do something with file f (it will be closed for you automatically when the block terminates
```

Another problem may be that you are opening the file with an invalid flag, `"x"` if the file already exists. Try, `"w"`:

```
with open(new_file_path, "w") as f:
    # do something with file f (it will be closed for you automatically when the block terminates
```

Comment: What if you invoke the script from another directory? It's creating the file in the other directory, not where the script is - so that would be one reason.

Comment: @Levon To what question is your comment an answer to?

Comment: I meant to refer to this. "Opening a file without specifying any directory should by definition place the file in the current working directory:" I'm starting a  Python script in my home directory (let's say `/home/levon`) from some other directory (`/root`) . The script is creating a log file `open('logfile.txt', a)`, but rather than creating the logfile in `/home/levon` where the script is located, it creates it in `/root`.

Comment: @Levon I agree with you 100% and nowhere in my post did I say anything contradictory to that (or ask a question). I said, **... and the current working directory (usually the place from which the script was invoked), given by `os.getcwd()`.** I am saying that the current working directory by default (unless you change it) is the directory from which the script is invoked. In your example that would be `/root`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `os.getcwd` to get the crrent working directory

```
import os

dir_path = os.getcwd()
new_file_path = str(os.path.join(dir_path, 'mynewfile.txt'))
open(new_file_path, "x")
```

Comment: And if you just did `open('mynewfile.txt', 'x')`, what directory would the file it go into if not the current working directory?

Comment: who knows ? :/ -\(' ')/-

Comment: Answer: The current working directory. In other words, there is no reason for calling `os.getcwd()` to put a file into the current working directory.

Comment: you got A+ for this solution, congrats boohoo